# how to create .cod,.cso,.debug,.jad,.jar,.rapc files in standard and web folders in blackberry(eclipse plug_in)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, blackberry

i am completly new to bb development,when i saw an old sample project for reference i came to know that in deliverables folder i have .csl,.cso,.debug,.jad,.jar,.rapc files created.when i searched in google i found that it is related to bb-ant-tools.

while when i created a project in my personnal computer i doesn't find those files in my project (in my pc i have just downloaded bb 7.1 from http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/)

what are these files?why ,how and when should i create them?what is the use of creating them?what is bb-ant-tools and why should i use bb-ant-tools?

Comment: first apply for signing keys. then install the keys on your system. after that right click the project and sign with signature tool. then u will get all the files.